# Vaadin/OSGi : ScssStylesheet class not found

Tags: java, osgi, sass, vaadin

I use vaadin and OSGi to create a modular application. After a long fight, I was able to deploy successfully the application. However, I can't load the style. When I try to access to 
`http://localhost:8080/myapp/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/styles.css`
I got the following exception:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/sass/internal/ScssStylesheet
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveOnTheFlyCompiledScss(VaadinServlet.java:957)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN(VaadinServlet.java:790)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticResources(VaadinServlet.java:760)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:257)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveOnTheFlyCompiledScss(VaadinServlet.java:957)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN(VaadinServlet.java:790)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticResources(VaadinServlet.java:760)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:257)
com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)[/code]
```

`com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet` class is offered by vaadin-theme-compiler-7.x.x.jar but the server doesn't import this package. Then, I "hacked" the vaadin server bundle by adding `DynamicImport-Package: *` in vaadin server's MANIFEST. The previous exception does not appear but I got the same for `org.w3c.css.sac.CSSException`.

Note that by deploying the application .war file on tomcat, I had no error and the app looks like I expected (because all libraries are added under WEB-INF/lib and tomcat add them on the class loader). So, the problem is pure OSGi.

Answer (score 2):

based on the Vaadin 7.1.3 bundles, the following changes need to be made:

- import com.vaadin.theme-compiler in com.vaadin.server
- import org.w3c.css.sac in com.vaadin.shared.deps and com.vaadin.theme-compiler
- provide a ScssStylesheetResolver via ScssStylesheet.setStylesheetResolvers which loads from bundle resources, not (only) filesystem / classloader as the default implementation.
- if you import parts of the original themes in your theme, consider creating it as a fragment to com.vaadin.themes, which in turn can then be used as a base for the ScssStylesheetResolver

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a packaging bug in Vaadin which should be reported to the authors. If the core Vaadin bundle needs to access classes from the package `com.vaadin.sass.internal` then it should include that in its `Import-Package` header.

With respect to `org.w3c.css.sac`, you don't specify which bundle throws an error but it sounds like the same kind of problem. Whichever bundle uses that package should import it via Import-Package.

Comment: I noticed it in Vaadin forum (thread [here](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3177168).). I had this error because Vaadin tried to compile styles.scss on the fly when it is requested. In OSGi environment, it doesn't work well. So I used a compiled theme (ie: .css file).